# Why isn't the gear menu there?

Tags: shutdown, menu

I would like to shut down this computer but the button isn't in the upper right corner. 
Ubuntu 13.10. Changing the theme to default doesn't help.

Comment: This happened to me once but was only temporary.  Try rebooting from a terminal.  Press CTRL+ALT+T to open one: Enter `sudo shutdown -r now` enter your password and it will reboot logon again.  If this fixes it let us know so we can close the question if not edit your question to say you have tried this (and it didn't work).  Until this is fixed you can shutdown from the terminal with `sudo shutdown now`

Comment: After reboot the button was there again.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `indicator-session` might have crashed/failed to load. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run:

```
restart unity-panel-service
```

If that doesn't work, try running:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-session/indicator-session-service
```

in a terminal.

**Note.** The `x86_64-linux-gnu` part is for Ubuntu 64-bit, if you are using Ubuntu 32-bit you should change it to `i386-linux-gnu`

Comment: Looks like a good answer. Shame that I didn't get to try that because I managed to shut down the computer another way.